# SilverStripe: how to get only some of the fields of Model

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, silverstripe

Let's say I have Member model

I want to get only array of Member Names, and email. How can I achieve that.
Possible Solution :

```
$members = Member::get(); // it will gives me all members.

$data = [];

foreach($members as $member){
     $temp['Name'] = $member->Name;
     $temp['Email'] = $member->Email;
     $data[] = $temp;
     unset($temp);
}
//got data into $data
```

But I directly want to select only *Name* and *Email* is it possible in **Silver Stripe** ?

As I know [laravel select](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#selects) model it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

*Actually your question was misleading or I did't able to understand what you wanted to say so I have given solution for Laravel.* But any way try with the below code.

```
$sqlQuery = new SQLSelect();
$sqlQuery->setFrom('your_table_name');
$sqlQuery->selectField('Name', 'Email');

// Get the raw SQL (optional) and parameters
$rawSQL = $sqlQuery->sql($parameters);

// Execute and return a Query object
$result = $sqlQuery->execute();

// Iterate over results
foreach($result as $row) {
  echo $row['Name'];
  echo $row['Email'];
}
```

---

Reference:

- [SQL Query](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/model/sql_query/#select)

Use Full Links

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12454867/5019802
- https://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/data-model-questions/show/51892

Comment: I want this kind of in silver stripe [Warning] class_exists() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: i think i must have to loop those data

Answer (score 0):

According to the api docs, [`->setQueriedColumns()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.5/class-DataList.html#_setQueriedColumns) should do the trick to limit the columns in the query. It returns a DataList you can convert to an array using [`->toArray()`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.5/class-DataList.html#method_toArray):

```
$members = Member::get()->setQueriedColumns(['Name', 'Email'])->toArray();
```

Comment: Nope checked it will returns all member model value.

Answer (score -1):

```
$members=(array) $members;

foreach($members as $member){
 $temp['Name'] = $member['Name'];
 $temp['Email'] = $member['Email'];
}
```

See your result having only two members name and email in array `$temp`:

```
print_r($temp);
```